# Number of days between 2 dates

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how to find the difference between 2 dates in days, however when trying the following:

```
DateTime O = d_out;
DateTime I = d_in;
TimeSpan span = I.Subtract(O);
var days = span.Days;
```

( d_out & d_in are variables holding date values)

It returns the difference between days only and doesn't return the number of days for months and year.

To give you a clearer understanding the code above returns "-1" for difference between dates "06/08/18"(06 Aug 18) & "05/09/18"(05 Sept 18), how can i get it to output "30" instead?

Comment: [The documentation of `TimeSpan` is your friend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A `TimeSpan` is only a period of time if you want to convert that to months and years, you'll have to do it some other way.

Comment: @phuzi I've made an edit

Comment: TimeSpan only knows about "days" and smaller, as "months" and "years" don't have a clear length (month=28..31 days, year=365 or 366 or maybe 365.25 days)

Comment: Edit your code and create an example of EXACT values you have. We do not know which date is which variable or are you PARSING date from string, which might lead to wrong results.

Comment: There is no way you get -1 from those dates even if they are being parsed as month first.  I'd suggest you replace `d_out` and `d_in` with something like `new DateTime(2018,9,5)` to make sure your code is running with the actual dates you expect then figure out why the variables have dates that are only one day apart.

Comment: Are you *sure* your dates contain those values? Print out `Day`, `Month` and `Year` of each to check. How exactly are you getting those values into those variables? Add that code to your question and especially any formatting strings, as suggested by AdamV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're parsing months as minutes. [In `DateTime` string formatting, `M` is month and `m` is minute.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
      var d1=new DateTime(2018, 1, 6, 0, 8, 0);
      var d2=new DateTime(2018, 1, 5, 0, 9, 0);
      var span = d2.Subtract(d1);
      Console.WriteLine(span.TotalDays);
      Console.WriteLine(span.Days);
  }
}
```

Result:

```
-0.999305555555556
0
```

Comment: That's a good guess but the OP is saying that `Days` is -1 where as here it's 0.  Ultimately we cannot tell what the issue is without the code that produces the dates in question.

Comment: @juharr I'm going by the OP's comment to JoshBerke's answer where he says "using the above dates i get this answer "-0,999305555555556""

Comment: @AdamV You are right!! .. I've been parsing it incorrectly. Thanks a million, It all works

Answer (score 4):

`span.TotalDays` will give you the total number of days

Yes it does

using System;

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var d1=DateTime.Parse("1/2/18");
        var d2=DateTime.Parse("2/3/18");
        Console.WriteLine(d2.Subtract(d1).TotalDays);
    }
}
```

outputs 32

See my [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WS0Ao9#)

Comment: This does not give me the total number of days across two different months

Comment: @LeevenPersad Yes it does.

Comment: @Dominik var days = span.TotalDays; using the above dates i get this answer "-0,999305555555556"

Comment: @LeevenPersad try initialising the dates in code. There is plenty of code in the answers to do that. Please doublecheck that the dates contain the date that you expect.

Comment: Please check the the dates itself, `TotalDays` and `Days` should not be any different since you have full dates without any hours or minutes. A bit more details in my answer.

Comment: Your example is not entirely correct, because the result will differ depending on the locale your code is run. It's more robust to initialize using a constructor (at least for the sake of testing if you don't need locale handling).

Comment: @LeevenPersad What is *your* value of `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` (assuming you are parsing strings into dates)?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing en_US

Comment: @LeevenPersad - post your formatting string. I guarantee you're parsing months as minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I have run this in the C# interactive and works just fine:

```
var start = new DateTime(2018, 8, 6);
var end = new DateTime(2018, 9, 5);
var span = end - start;
span.Days
30
```

Are you sure it's not some date formatting issue like e.g. you are running with  american locale that interprets first number as month?

I would suggest that you verify in debug which exact dates do you have after both variables are assigned.

Comment: I am using System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat so the format is in order, for some reason when i use span.Days or span.TotalDays it only calculates the difference of the days and doesnt take months and year into consideration

Comment: I would highly suggest to verify the dates in runtime. Locale parsing errors happen often. In runtime you can watch the variables to know for sure which dates are there.